# how to check for updates in firefox less frequently?

Tags: firefox

I'd like to have Firefox automatically check for updates for itself and any add-ons, but only once or twice a week, not every time it starts up.  Is there a way to configure firefox this way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> app.update.interval (Integer). The
>   value entered here specifies the
>   amount of time, in seconds, that
>   Firefox waits before checking for
>   updates. The default being 86400, aka
>   1 day. Of late the main Firefox
>   releases have been due to security
>   issues and as such it would be wise to
>   leave this at the default  to ensure
>   you get notified of such updates ASAP.

Just open about:config page in address bar, enter `app.update.interval` and change the value accordingly.

Comment: ...which also implies Firefox does not really check *every time it's started*, but only once a day. (The comment about security updates surely makes me *not* want to change that to more than a day.)